# Can I use '\n' in a secret value?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I have a secret value that I obviously cannot share, but I'll give an example in what i mean, I'm trying to push it using the CLI where I want it, but it's giving me an error, so im assuming it's the escape lines and spacing. the secret looks something like this

```
----BEGIN----
123456
123456
123456
----END----
```

when I push it using the cli, im supposed to push it in a JSON format. so the formatting above does not work since it's not proper JSON.
what I end up pushing is this :
`----BEGIN----123456123456123456----END----` so
My Question is, could I do the following?

```
----BEGIN----\n123456\n123456\n123456\n----END----
```

Thank you so much

Comment: This is a weird question since it seems to me like in the time it took you to ask it you could have just tried it. In any case your question is also not mentioning what CLI (or more specifically what command you are executing) and/or what kind of secret you are talking about so nobody can help you regardless. The gcloud secret command can just take a file path so you don't have this issue if that is what you are talking about: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/create#--data-file

Comment: I'm still new in my field and scared to break something lol, I will give it a try though and keep an update here I guess in case anyone ever is wondering about it

Comment: Please include in your questions what you tried and what happened. It's untrue that you are "supposed to push it in a JSON format". The `gcloud secrets create` documentation [EXAMPLES](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/create#EXAMPLES)  4&5 both show one way you could print the above content and pipe it into the `gcloud` command's `--data-file` flag. NB `-` is used as a synonym for `/dev/stdout` here.

Comment: According to the text interpreter, the \n can be interpreted or not. It's only a formating issue, not a secret manager issue.

Comment: @DazWilkin the thing is I'm using credhub for that, and its not allowing me to add secret value using the webpage, its giving me an error that no app-guid is tied to it, so I tried the command line and it did work pushing it through it, but I had to push the secrets as a JSON format for it to be accepted according to credhub default documentation. but the documentation did not mention anything about escape characters and such so I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: You didn't mention credhub in your question. You said CLI which I assumed to be Google Cloud CLI aka `gcloud`. This is one reason why I recommend you include more details in your question so that we can better help.